# How to return jsx after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I have a loading state that I want to show only if the loading takes more than 1 second (since I don't want to keep showing the loader even if the loading time is just a few milliseconds).

This is the one that shows the loader regardless of the speed of loading:

```
if(loading) {
    return <div className="loader" />;
}
```

This is the one with setTimeout:

```
if(loading) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return <div className="loader" />;
    }, 1000);
}
```

I understand that the return statement applies to `setTimeout` and not the component that's why it doesn't work.

Should I then create a state first (e.g. `isLoadingSlow`) which I will change to true after 1 second in the `setTimeout` callback? Then based from that state, then I would do a return statement with the loader jsx?

Comment: I don't think there is a way yet to detect how much time the component is taking to load. React has proposed this feature of async rendering in the future version though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: this is an answer written based on an answer that was deleted from this post.

I think you need to have two variables, one is loader, another one is show loader. After one second, if it is still loading, we should update the stat to show the loader, otherwise it won't be shown.

```js
state= {
   loading: true,
   showLoader: false
}

componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(this.loading){
          this.setState({ showLoader: true })
      }
    }, 1000);
}
render() {
   if(this.state.showLoader) {
        return <div className="loader" />;
   }
}
```

Comment: Means there's no running away from making that component a class-based one?

Comment: Well, I am not sure to be honest. I make all my components class based anyway.

Comment: @catandmouse Yes. The component should have a state and it thus it needs to be a class.